# fuse: bad mount point `/mnt': Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: sshfs, fuse

I needed to locally edit remote files on my server, so I tried to mount the whole remote file system (`/`) on my local system with SSHFS like so:

```
 $ sshfs username@domain.com:// /mnt -p 22
```

**Then it stuck (cursor blinking, no output)**, so obviously I cancelled it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

After that, the mount point folder `/mnt` became sort of unusable, unreachable (you name it) and kept returning me this error message on any attempt to access it:

`` fuse: bad mount point `/mnt': Transport endpoint is not connected ``

And it took this weird look in its parent folder:

```
$ ls -l /
...
d?????????   ? ?    ?        ?            ? mnt`
...
```

#### How can I resolve the error and get back to normal?

#### What should I do to be able to use SSHFS?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

#### 1. Kill all `sshfs` processes

- Either with `killall` command:

  ```
  killall sshfs
  ```

  or selectively:
- Find all running `sshfs` processes:

  ```
  ps -ef | grep sshfs | grep -v grep
  ```

  Say you've got two of them running:

  ```
  $ ps -ef | grep sshfs | grep -v grep
  root     10906  5170  0 07:14 pts/0    00:00:00 sudo sshfs
  root     10907 10906  0 07:14 pts/0    00:00:00 sshfs
  ```
- Now kill them both or selectively by identifying them by their PID:

  ```
  sudo kill -9 10906 10907
  ```

#### 2. Unmount your mount point

```
sudo umount -l /mnt
```

#### 3. Edit `/etc/fuse.conf` so you never meet the `` fuse: bad mount point `/mnt': Transport endpoint is not connected `` error again:

- Open it as root with your favorite editor, for example

  ```
  sudo atom /etc/fuse.conf
  ```
- Uncomment the `user_allow_other` line.
- Save and close.

#### 4. Use SSHFS with the following options:

```
sudo sshfs \
-d \
-o allow_other \
-o reconnect \
-o ServerAliveInterval=15 \
user@domain.com:/ /mnt \
-p 12345 \
-C
```

- `-d` turns debug mode on (gives more output)
- `-o` stands for "option"
- `-p` allows you to specify port number
- `-C` turns on compression

#### Sources:

- https://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/2470-correct-use-ps-ef-grep.html
- http://slopjong.de/2013/04/26/sshfs-transport-endpoint-is-not-connected
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184965/open-file-from-remote-computer-on-host-computer

Comment: Didn't work for me, still hangs.

Comment: Didn't work for me, but I realized that I can go through the folders of the mount via terminal. This indicated that Nautilus has messed up!. To confirm this, I installed Krusader and navigated to that folder without any error or issue. At this point I suggest you quickly check with terminal and another file manager instead of mounting and unmounting multiple times and etc.

Comment: In my case I figured out it wasn't really hanging, I was just trying to reach something unreachable, and probably didn't wait long enough. Cursor might also have not been blinking. Got me the same error message after ctrl-c.

Comment: Key here is to use `sudo` with `umount`. Without it messages like "Device or resource busy" or "Transport endpoint is not connected" pop up.

Comment: I was using [Android File Transfer](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Media_Transfer_Protocol#Android_File_Transfer) (`aft-mtp-mount`) and `sudo umount -l /mnt` worked for me

Comment: sudo umount -l /mnt/<path> worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

There is another way. Try something:

```
$ fusermount -u /mnt
```